# Delete identical rows so that values in one column are summed up in Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, julia

I know it is possible to delete identical rows from data in Julia DataFrames, but is it possible to sum up elements of one column of the identical rows while the identical rows are deleted?

I mean for the data below I want to sum up the `cycles` of the identical rows without summing up `amp` and `mean`.

```
julia> Data1
8×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ amp   │ mean  │ cycles │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 2   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 3   │ 350.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 4   │ 150.0 │ -50.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 5   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 6   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 7   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 0.5    │
│ 8   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 0.5    │
```

Then the data would look like the following:

```
julia> Data1
5×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ amp   │ mean  │ cycles │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 2.0    │
│ 2   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 2.0    │
│ 3   │ 350.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 4   │ 150.0 │ -50.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 5   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least the following options

```
julia> aggregate(df, [:amp, :mean], sum)
5×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ amp   │ mean  │ cycles_sum │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 2.0        │
│ 2   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 2.0        │
│ 3   │ 350.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0        │
│ 4   │ 150.0 │ -50.0 │ 1.0        │
│ 5   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0        │

julia> by(df, [:amp, :mean], df->DataFrame(cycles=sum(df[:cycles])))
5×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ amp   │ mean  │ cycles │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 2.0    │
│ 2   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 2.0    │
│ 3   │ 350.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 4   │ 150.0 │ -50.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 5   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
```

Both can be found in the DataFrames.jl [documentation](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/split_apply_combine.html).

I found the latter to be faster in a quick and dirty benchmark.

Note that as has been pointed out in the comments one can use the much nicer notation `@by(df, [:amp, :mean], cycles=sum(:cycles))` when `using DataFramesMeta` ([github repo](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl)).

**UPDATE:**

As has been mentioned in the comments the solutions above sum up the cycle values of rows which are identical only with respect to their `amp` and `mean` values, i.e. they can in principle have different `cycle` values. In case one wants to distinguish rows with different `cycle` values as well it is easy to adapt the second approach above:

`@by(df, [:amp, :mean, :cycles], cycles_sum=sum(:cycles))`

**On a side note, reproduction of the dataset:**

```
julia> s = "amp,mean,cycles
       50.0,250.0,1.0
       150.0,250.0,1.0
       350.0,150.0,1.0
       150.0,-50.0,1.0
       50.0,250.0,1.0
       150.0,250.0,1.0
       450.0,150.0,0.5
       450.0,150.0,0.5"

julia> using DataFrames, CSV

julia> df = CSV.read(IOBuffer(s))
8×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ amp   │ mean  │ cycles │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 2   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 3   │ 350.0 │ 150.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 4   │ 150.0 │ -50.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 5   │ 50.0  │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 6   │ 150.0 │ 250.0 │ 1.0    │
│ 7   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 0.5    │
│ 8   │ 450.0 │ 150.0 │ 0.5    │
```

Comment: Or use `@by` from `DataFramesMeta` like `@by(df, [:amp, :mean], cycles=sum(:cycles))`.

Comment: With these, you're not guaranteed to have identical rows as the question states. `cycles` is not necessarily the same across rows when you're doing the summation.

Comment: @niczky12 indeed. If rows should really only be summed up if they are identical (including the `cycles` value) one can simply do `@by(df, [:amp, :mean, :cycles], cycles_sum=sum(:cycles))`.